# Problemas para envio de e-mail asp.net.mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

O servidor SMTP requer uma conexão segura ou o cliente não foi autenticado?

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string login)
{
    try
    {
        var tbuscar = new UsuarioAplicacao();
        var retorno = tbuscar.ListarPorLogin(login);

        if (retorno != null)
        {
            string infLogin = retorno.login;
            string infSenha = retorno.senha;
            string infNome = retorno.nomeusuario;
            int infId = retorno.idusuario;

            string texto = "O seu login é : " + infLogin + " é sua senha é : " + infSenha;

            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.mail.yahoo.com", 587);
            smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("itasouza@yahoo.com.br", "senha");
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;

            MailMessage m = new MailMessage();
            m.Subject = "Recuperação de senha";
            m.Body = "Segue informações sobre usuário e senha: \n" + texto;
            m.To.Add(infLogin);
            m.From = new MailAddress("itasouza@yahoo.com.br");
            m.IsBodyHtml = true;
            smtp.Send(m);

            TempData["msg"] = "E-mail enviado com sucesso";    
        }
        else
        {
            TempData["Erro"] = "Usuário não cadastrado.";
        }

        ModelState.Clear();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        TempData["Erro"] =  ex.Message;
    }

    return View();
}
```

Comment: Talvez esteja usando a senha real do Gmail, o Google não permite este tipo de operação. Veja como criar senha para aplicativos menos seguros aqui: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255

Comment: Esse código seu funcionaria com o yahoo, tenho uma aplicação rodando que praticamente igual ao seu código. Se o google não for uma obrigação para você tenta com o yahoo.

Comment: @Ricardo, vou fazer um teste usando o yahoo

Comment: Qual o erro? Aqui no codeproject tem um bom exemplo: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/520998/Send-Email-from-Yahoo-GMail-Hotmail-Csharp

Answer (score 1):

Com o yahoo ficaria assim:

```
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.mail.yahoo.com", 587);
smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential
      ("email@yahoo.com.br", "senha");
smtp.EnableSsl = true;
smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;

MailMessage m= new MailMessage();
m.Subject = "Assunto do email";
m.Body = "corpo do email";
m.To.Add("para@emailcom.br");
m.From = new MailAddress("email@yahoo.com.br");
m.IsBodyHtml = true;

smtp.Send(m);
```

Comment: @Riscardo , fiz o exemplo :O servidor SMTP requer uma conexão segura ou o cliente não foi autenticado. A resposta do servidor foi: 5.7.1 Authentication required

Comment: Estou usando o windows 8.1

Comment: Testou o código exatamente assim? Tem alguma configuração de segurança diferente nesse e-mail? Meu código roda como está aí. Eu passei por esse erro quando estava fazendo e cheguei nesse resultado.

Comment: troquei o código da pergunta, veja lá, agradeço a ajuda!